# Algorithm to calculate paving pattern

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Is there any feasible algorithm to calculate a pattern for various paving tiles? I am looking for something where I can specify sth like having four different stones of various sizes and amounts, and I want to get a pattern to pave an area. I vaguely remember having read about such an algorithm in logistics, but cant come up with any useful hint. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Would this help ? https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/shimada/papers/00-tvc-miyata.pdf

Comment: what about some search for bin-packing of polygon ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort the tiles and use a treemap. Put the first tile into the tree and split it along both axis. Put the next tile into the best free space. Rince and repeat.